# Iterate and scrape data from all the links stored in an csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Firstly, I am scraping data for a single URL and I am scraping name, connection, location, and job experiences. Now suppose if I have 1000's of URL stored in an excel with column name URL, in that case is it possible to loop through those URLs stored in an excel file? Her's my code which extracts data for single URL only.

```
link = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/tresayles/'
driver.get(link)
#scroll to the bottom of the page
height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
for scrol in range(100,height,100):
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{scrol})")
    time.sleep(0.5)
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
try:
    name_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flex-1 mr5'})
except:
    name_div=None
try:
    name_loc = name_div.find_all('ul')
except:
    name_loc=None
try:
    name = name_loc[0].find('li').get_text().strip()
except:
    name=None
try:
    loc = name_loc[1].find('li').get_text().strip()
except:
    loc=None
try:       
    connection = name_loc[1].find_all('li')
except:
    connection=None
try:
    connection = connection[1].get_text().strip()
except:
    Connection=None
info = []
info.append(name)
info.append(loc)
info.append(connection)
info

#experience setion
try:
    exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
except:
    exp_section=None
try:
    exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
except:
    exp_section=None
try:
    div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
except:
    div_tag=None
try:
    a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
except:
    a_tag=None
try:
    job_title = a_tag.find('h3').get_text().strip()
except:
    job_title=None
try:
    company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
except:
    company_name=None
try:
    joining_date = a_tag.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
except:
    joining_date=None
try:
    exp = a_tag.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
except:
    exp=None
info.append(company_name)
info.append(job_title)
info.append(joining_date)
info.append(exp)
info

df = pd.DataFrame(info).T
df.columns = ['name', 'location', 'connection', 'company', 'position', 'duration', 'tenure']
df
```

```
name  location connection company position        duration      tenure
abc    IND      500+       xyz     good position    2018-2019     1 yr
```

for one link it gives me the above OP

in that similar way i want all the OP for all link stored in csv or excel file

please help me to get my desired OP

Comment: Never use bare `except:`s – they hide all exceptions, making debugging nearly impossible.

Comment: But to answer your actual question – yes, of course it's possible to loop over a list of strings. What have you tried to that effect?

Comment: ```
with open('test1.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig' ) as f:

    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for line in reader:

#         url = line[0]

        link = line[0]

```


i have tried this, but it shows ` None None None None None None None`

Comment: Your original post mentions Excel files, yet now you have a CSV..?

Comment: @AKX sorry for the inconvinience i have edited and changed to csv

Comment: Well, this is really a 3-part problem: (a) read the URLs into a list from your CSV (b) wrap your current code into a function that accepts an URL and returns the data (c) combine the two to run your function for each URL and save the results.

Comment: @AKX i have tried a lot my friend, after a lot of try finally i have to post this in SO, can you write that loop part only. Suppose the code is Scrape_code the part which I have posted. Now what i have to write?. Please help dear

Comment: And suppose the csv file is CSV_url.csv